# MariaDB Connector/c++ throwing exception

Tags: c++, mysql, cmake, mariadb, connector

I am trying to connect to my MariaDB instance using the MariaDB Connector/c++. Here is the code where I tried to use the already compiled version of the connector:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <mariadb/conncpp.hpp>
    
    int main()
    {
            std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    
    try
    {
        // Instantiate Driver
        sql::Driver* driver = sql::mariadb::get_driver_instance();
    

    // Configure Connection
    sql::SQLString url("jdbc:mariadb://X.X.X.X:3306/myMariaDB");
    
    sql::Properties properties({
        {"user", "root"},
        {"password", "myPassword"},
        {"useTls", "true"},
        {"tlsCA", "myFile.pem"}
        });
    

    // Establish Connection
    std::unique_ptr<sql::Connection> conn(driver->connect(url, properties));

    std::cout << "I connected successfully!";
    

    conn->close();
}
catch (sql::SQLException& e)
{
    std::cerr << "Error Connecting to MariaDB Platform: "
        << e.what() << std::endl;

    // Exit (Failed)
    return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Running the code throws exception at the //Establish Connection line:

**Exception thrown: read access violation.
other.theString._Mypair._Myval2 was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEF.**

Searching the internet people suggested to recompile the connector source which I got from Github https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-cpp#readme

I tried to compile the source using VS 2019 and CMake. I have to say that this is my first encounter with CMake and I know very little about it. It seems that both are failing to build the cloned repo. below is the error I get form VS 2019 which is very similar to what I get from CMake. I also get an error in the "Error List" tab in VS 2019 : CMAke Error at libmariadb/cmake/version_info.cmake:15 (STRING):...:

```
1> CMake generation started for default configuration: 'x64-Debug'.
1> Command line: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe" /c "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\chcp.com 65001 >NUL && "C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"  -G "Ninja"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Debug" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="C:\Users\RezaNoAdmin\Desktop\mariadb-connector-cpp\out\install\x64-Debug" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"  -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\Ninja\ninja.exe" "C:\Users\RezaNoAdmin\Desktop\mariadb-connector-cpp" 2>&1"
1> Working directory: C:\Users\RezaNoAdmin\Desktop\mariadb-connector-cpp\out\build\x64-Debug
1> [CMake] -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30133.0
1> [CMake] -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30133.0
1> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
1> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
1> [CMake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
1> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compile features
1> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
1> [CMake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
1> [CMake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
1> [CMake] -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
1> [CMake] -- Detecting C compile features
1> [CMake] -- Detecting C compile features - done
1> [CMake] -- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG= /MTd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
1> [CMake] -- CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG= /MTd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
1> [CMake] -- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE= /MT /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
1> [CMake] -- CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE= /MT /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
1> [CMake] -- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO= /MT /Zi /O2 /Ob1 /DNDEBUG
1> [CMake] -- CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO= /MT /Zi /O2 /Ob1 /DNDEBUG
1> [CMake] -- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL= /MT /O1 /Ob1 /DNDEBUG
1> [CMake] -- CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL= /MT /O1 /Ob1 /DNDEBUG
1> [CMake] -- MariaDB Connector ODBC: INSTALL_BINDIR=
1> [CMake] -- MariaDB Connector ODBC: INSTALL_LIBDIR=/mariadb
1> [CMake] -- MariaDB Connector ODBC: INSTALL_PCDIR=/pkgconfig
1> [CMake] -- MariaDB Connector ODBC: INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR=include/mariadb
1> [CMake] -- MariaDB Connector ODBC: INSTALL_DOCDIR=share/doc/mariadbcpp
1> [CMake] -- MariaDB Connector ODBC: INSTALL_LICENSEDIR=share/doc/mariadbcpp
1> [CMake] -- MariaDB Connector ODBC: INSTALL_PLUGINDIR=plugin
1> [CMake] -- Generate MSI package: ON
1> [CMake] -- Sign MSI package: OFF
1> [CMake] -- Setting deafault value for WITH_SSL for libmariadb build to ON
1> [CMake] -- Running C/C cmake scripts
1> [CMake] -- Found Git: C:/Windows/System32/git  
1> [CMake] == Configuring MariaDB Connector/C
1> [CMake] CMake Warning (dev) at libmariadb/CMakeLists.txt:19 (PROJECT):
1> [CMake]   Policy CMP0048 is not set: project() command manages VERSION variables.
1> [CMake]   Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0048" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
1> [CMake]   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]   The following variable(s) would be set to empty:
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]     PROJECT_VERSION
1> [CMake]     PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR
1> [CMake]     PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR
1> [CMake]     PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH
1> [CMake] This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] -- Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
1> [CMake] -- MariaDB Connector C: INSTALL_BINDIR=bin
1> [CMake] -- MariaDB Connector C: INSTALL_LIBDIR=/mariadb
1> [CMake] -- MariaDB Connector C: INSTALL_PCDIR=/pkgconfig
1> [CMake] -- MariaDB Connector C: INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR=include/mariadb
1> [CMake] -- MariaDB Connector C: INSTALL_DOCSDIR=
1> [CMake] -- MariaDB Connector C: INSTALL_PLUGINDIR=plugin
1> [CMake] -- MariaDB Connector C: LIBMARIADB_STATIC_NAME mariadbclient
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file alloca.h
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file alloca.h - not found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file arpa/inet.h
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file arpa/inet.h - not found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file dlfcn.h
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file dlfcn.h - not found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file fcntl.h
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file fcntl.h - found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file float.h
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file float.h - found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file limits.h
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file limits.h - found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file linux/limits.h
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file linux/limits.h - not found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file pwd.h
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file pwd.h - not found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file sched.h
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file sched.h - not found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file select.h
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file select.h - not found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file signal.h
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file signal.h - found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file stddef.h
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file stddef.h - found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file stdint.h
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file stdint.h - found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file stdlib.h
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file stdlib.h - found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file string.h
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file string.h - found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file strings.h
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file strings.h - not found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file sys/ioctl.h
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file sys/ioctl.h - not found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file sys/select.h
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file sys/select.h - not found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file sys/socket.h
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file sys/socket.h - not found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file sys/types.h
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file sys/types.h - found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file sys/stat.h
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file sys/stat.h - found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file sys/un.h
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file sys/un.h - not found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file unistd.h
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file unistd.h - not found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file utime.h
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file utime.h - not found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file ucontext.h
1> [CMake] -- Looking for include file ucontext.h - not found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for alloca
1> [CMake] -- Looking for alloca - not found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for dlerror
1> [CMake] -- Looking for dlerror - not found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for dlopen
1> [CMake] -- Looking for dlopen - not found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for fcntl
1> [CMake] -- Looking for fcntl - not found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for memcpy
1> [CMake] -- Looking for memcpy - found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for nl_langinfo
1> [CMake] -- Looking for nl_langinfo - not found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for setlocale
1> [CMake] -- Looking for setlocale - found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for poll
1> [CMake] -- Looking for poll - not found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for getpwuid
1> [CMake] -- Looking for getpwuid - not found
1> [CMake] -- Looking for cuserid
1> [CMake] -- Looking for cuserid - not found
1> [CMake] -- Check size of char *
1> [CMake] -- Check size of char * - done
1> [CMake] -- Check size of int
1> [CMake] -- Check size of int - done
1> [CMake] -- Check size of long
1> [CMake] -- Check size of long - done
1> [CMake] -- Check size of long long
1> [CMake] -- Check size of long long - done
1> [CMake] -- Check size of size_t
1> [CMake] -- Check size of size_t - done
1> [CMake] -- Check size of uchar
1> [CMake] -- Check size of uchar - failed
1> [CMake] -- Check size of uint
1> [CMake] -- Check size of uint - failed
1> [CMake] -- Check size of ulong
1> [CMake] -- Check size of ulong - failed
1> [CMake] -- Check size of int8
1> [CMake] -- Check size of int8 - failed
1> [CMake] -- Check size of uint8
1> [CMake] -- Check size of uint8 - failed
1> [CMake] -- Check size of int16
1> [CMake] -- Check size of int16 - failed
1> [CMake] -- Check size of uint16
1> [CMake] -- Check size of uint16 - failed
1> [CMake] -- Check size of int32
1> [CMake] -- Check size of int32 - failed
1> [CMake] -- Check size of uint32
1> [CMake] -- Check size of uint32 - failed
1> [CMake] -- Check size of int64
1> [CMake] -- Check size of int64 - failed
1> [CMake] -- Check size of uint64
1> [CMake] -- Check size of uint64 - failed
1> [CMake] -- Check size of socklen_t
1> [CMake] -- Check size of socklen_t - failed
1> [CMake] -- TLS library/version: Schannel 10.0.19042
1> [CMake] -- SYSTEM_LIBS ws2_32;advapi32;kernel32;shlwapi;crypt32;secur32
1> [CMake] CMake Error at libmariadb/cmake/version_info.cmake:15 (STRING):
1> [CMake]   STRING sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments.
1> [CMake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
1> [CMake]   libmariadb/cmake/version_info.cmake:33 (GET_FILE_VERSION)
1> [CMake]   libmariadb/libmariadb/CMakeLists.txt:390 (SET_VERSION_INFO)
1> [CMake] -- SYSTEM processor: AMD64
1> [CMake] -- MariaDB Connector/c configuration:
1> [CMake] -- Static PLUGINS mysql_native_password;mysql_old_password;pvio_socket
1> [CMake] -- Dynamic PLUGINS dialog;client_ed25519;caching_sha2_password;sha256_password;auth_gssapi_client;mysql_clear_password;pvio_npipe;pvio_shmem
1> [CMake] -- CPack generation: ZIP
1> [CMake] -- SSL support: SCHANNEL Libs: secur32
1> [CMake] -- Zlib support: yes (using bundled zlib)
1> [CMake] -- Installation layout: DEFAULT
1> [CMake] -- Include files will be installed in include/mariadb
1> [CMake] -- Libraries will be installed in /mariadb
1> [CMake] -- Binaries will be installed in bin
1> [CMake] -- Documentation included from 
1> [CMake] -- Required: 
1> [CMake] -- Configuring to install libmariadb to /mariadb
1> [CMake] -- Configuring to install mysql_clear_password to plugin
1> [CMake] -- Configuring to install dialog to plugin
1> [CMake] -- Configuring to install client_ed25519 to plugin
1> [CMake] -- Configuring to install sha256_password to plugin
1> [CMake] -- Configuring to install caching_sha2_password to plugin
1> [CMake] -- Linking Connector/C library statically(mariadbclient)
1> [CMake] -- WiX directory: /bin/
1> [CMake] -- MSI package name mariadb-connector-cpp-1.0.2-win64.msi
1> [CMake] -- Configuring tests framework lib
1> [CMake] -- Configuring C/J junit tests port
1> [CMake] -- Configuring unit tests
1> [CMake] -- Configuring unit tests - examples
1> [CMake] -- Configuring unit tests - connection
1> [CMake] -- Configuring unit tests - databasemetadata
1> [CMake] -- Configuring unit tests - resultsetmetadata
1> [CMake] -- Configuring unit tests - resultset
1> [CMake] -- Configuring unit tests - savepoint
1> [CMake] -- Configuring unit tests - preparedstatement
1> [CMake] -- Configuring unit tests - parametermetadata
1> [CMake] -- Configuring unit tests - statement
1> [CMake] -- Configuring performance test - statement
1> [CMake] -- Configuring bugs test cases - unsorted
1> [CMake] -- Configuring test cases
1> [CMake] -- Package Name: mariadb-connector-cpp-1.0.2-windows-AMD64
1> [CMake] -- License File: C:/Users/RezaNoAdmin/Desktop/mariadb-connector-cpp/COPYING
1> [CMake] -- ReadMe File: C:/Users/RezaNoAdmin/Desktop/mariadb-connector-cpp/README
1> [CMake] -- Source Package Filename: mariadb-connector-cpp-1.0.2-src.ZIP
1> [CMake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
1> [CMake] See also "C:/Users/RezaNoAdmin/Desktop/mariadb-connector-cpp/out/build/x64-Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
1> [CMake] See also "C:/Users/RezaNoAdmin/Desktop/mariadb-connector-cpp/out/build/x64-Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
1> 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe' '/c "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\chcp.com 65001 >NUL && "C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"  -G "Ninja"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Debug" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="C:\Users\RezaNoAdmin\Desktop\mariadb-connector-cpp\out\install\x64-Debug" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"  -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\Ninja\ninja.exe" "C:\Users\RezaNoAdmin\Desktop\mariadb-connector-cpp" 2>&1"' execution failed with error: ''C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe' '/c "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\chcp.com 65001 >NUL && "C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"  -G "Ninja"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Debug" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="C:\Users\RezaNoAdmin\Desktop\mariadb-connector-cpp\out\install\x64-Debug" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"  -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\Ninja\ninja.exe" "C:\Users\RezaNoAdmin\Desktop\mariadb-connector-cpp" 2>&1"' returned with exit code: 1'.
```

I have ran out of ideas on how to resolve this. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the mariadb c++ connector site(https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-cpp)

1. git clone
   git clone https://github.com/MariaDB-Corporation/mariadb-connector-cpp.git
2. build with debug mode(default is Release with Debug info)
   cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG -DCONC_WITH_UNIT_TESTS=Off -DCONC_WITH_MSI=OFF -DWITH_SSL=SCHANNEL .
   cmake --build . --config DEBUG
3. replace previous library with debug..